# How can processes detach when I try to kill them?

Tags: linux, python, process, kill, qt

I have an application on Linux where I have to kill a whole process tree from within an application. The process tree looks like:

```
app
└── parent
    ├── child1
    ├── child2
    ├── child3
    ├── child4
    └── child5
```

Now I have problems when killing the process tree by killing `parent`: It often happens that several subprocesses are not being killed when I try to kill the `parent` process. After the kill signal the child processes appear "detached" as these are in the process tree not below the original application `app` anymore. How can that happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reliably killing a process tree is not a simple matter, there are a few gotchas, like:

- killing a parent doesn't typically kill its children
- killing by process group usually fails if the killer process is in the same process group because the killer is itself killed as well, typically before finishing its job
- identifying all descendants of a process is not trivial

You may want to got through my answers to these more or less related Q&As for details:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30980234/linux-the-most-reliable-way-to-terminate-a-family-of-processes
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31298392/i-need-to-trace-all-child-processes-created-by-given-process-in-linux-or-posix
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30780487/python-script-to-monitor-process-and-sub-processes

Comment: Thanks for the pointers. It made me aware of a few key facts and gotchas.

Answer (score 1):

Generally in POSIX systems it is not true, that killing parent process also kills it's child.

Especially if you use `kill -KILL`, after killing parent process child process became [orphan processes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orphan_process).

You can kill whole [process group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_group) or search processes by parent pid before killing parent. In shell it can be done using:

```
ps --ppid <parent_pid>
```

In python I would suggest using [psutil](http://pythonhosted.org/psutil/) library, especially [`Process.children`](http://pythonhosted.org/psutil/_modules/psutil.html#Process.children) method.

Comment: Also take a look at answers to [this](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/14815/process-descendants) question.